# Perl regular expression is not working

Tags: regex, perl, matching

Hello I am trying to fetch couple of things using a Perl script.

```
my $fileName = "I_Payment_OK_2";
my ($msgType, $OfaCode, $msgCount) = $parseFileName;

#my $msgType = $parseFileName;
print $OfaCode;
print $msgType;
print $msgCount;

# parse the values from filename
sub  parseFileName {
     # parse the message type
     if($fileName =~ m/^(I|O)/) {
        $var1 = $1;
     }  
     # parse the OFAC trace keyword
     if($fileName =~ m/^[A-Z_][A-Za-z_]([A-Z]+)\w(\d+)$/) {
        $var2 = $2;
        $var3 = $3;
     }
     # return the message type & OFAC trace
     return ($var1, $var2, $var3);
     #return $var1; 
}
```

Nothing is getting printed. Can anybody help me with this what is going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're never calling parseFileName(). Probably `my ($msgType, $OfaCode, $msgCount) = $parseFileName;` should be `my ($msgType, $OfaCode, $msgCount) = parseFileName();`

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answer, you should accept it by clicking the gray checkbox on the left :)

Comment: Can you look into the regex portion of the code seems like its not working.

Comment: Your regex requires the input to have only capital letters after the second character. The `Payment_OK` portion must match `([A-Z]+)`, which it does not.

Comment: I want fetch the OK and the number 2 ( as the example given in the code)

Comment: `$fileName =~ /([A-Z]+)_(\d+)$/` should do it, for the example. Since I have no idea what other input you might expect, this regex might not suit your situation.

Comment: Yes Lanzz from the point of the input I should be always expect cap char at the the place of OK and then at the end I should receive number :). Thank you.

Comment: @Borodin: avirup has rep 1, he might not know answers are supposed to be accepted.

Comment: @Borodin. No, asking to accept an answer as solution isn't wrong. In fact its well within SO accepted polices to guide users to accept answers. As accepting answer is **the** way to thank here.

Comment: @tuxuday: I agree, but the comment was made very soon after the question was posted and there was atill only one answer. Pushing for the OP to accept it was premature and should have been general advice to accept answers that worked for him rather than this particular one.

Comment: @Borodin: "pushing" the OP to formally accept an answer that they have already accepted in writing? really? well thank you for your criticism, and I'll make sure to word my comments in a more politically-correct manner in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You should *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of your program, and declare all variables at the point of their first use using `my`. This applies especially when you are asking for help with your code as this measure can quickly reveal many simple mistakes.

From the look of your code it seems that you should be using [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) instead.

This program splits the file name string at the underscores, and extracts the first and the last two fields.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fileName = "I_Payment_OK_2";

my ($msgType, $OfaCode, $msgCount) = (split /_/, $fileName)[0, -2, -1];

print $msgType, "\n";
print $OfaCode, "\n";
print $msgCount, "\n";
```

**output**

```
I
OK
2
```

Comment: Thanks Borodin for your valuable comment.